# gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\cache.properties.lock (Access is denied) in Android studio

Tags: android

Can someone please explain to me what this error means and how to resolve this cache.properties.lock  error in android studio ??

Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\lrana\AndroidStudioProjects\Umachi.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\cache.properties.lock (Access is denied)

> C:\Users\lrana\AndroidStudioProjects\Umachi.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\cache.properties.lock (Access is denied)

Comment: i deleted folder under the suggested directory by the error C:\Users\lrana\AndroidStudioProjects\Umachi.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\cache.properties.lock , and now project is building successfuly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like it's related to https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2795.

Try to to delete everything under C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches. There is a cache.properties.lock that is holding a global lock which is preventing you from running your script. Using MacOS you will find it in your home directory ~/.gradle/caches

Comment: i deleted folder under the suggested directory by the error C:\Users\lrana\AndroidStudioProjects\Umachi.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\cache.properties.lock  , and now project is  building successfuly.

Comment: Glad for you. You can accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 9):

had this problem on linux, the problem was that it was root owned.

```
sudo chown user:user -R ./2.2
```

in the ./gradle directory solved the problem

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the right approach - changing the ownership from `root` to the user and the default group of the user. This is the command which worked for me: 
`sudo chown -R $USER: ./4.8.1/`

Answer (score 1):

Solution for this is:

1. [image: step 1]
2. Go to `default Setting`
3. change `Service directory path` to local drive(first create `.gradle` folder)
4. [image: step 2]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has a weird situation, this may be a good check!

Check if the **.gradle** folder should not be hidden in the user home directory. for example **C:/Users/MyUserName/.gradle**

Hidden? That's the cause.

use window explorer and navigate into .gradle using the example path to your home directory

Right Click -> Properties -> uncheck **Hidden**
Restart Android Studio!

**NOTE:**
In my case, invalidating cache dint worked, deleting .gradle folder dint worked.

Answer (score -1):

Go to that location which error is pointing then delete all those items whose access is denied one by one... it helped for me, hopefully it would help for u too....

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!