# During gradle downloading gradle3.3-all.zip.part file always has 0 KB size

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have downloaded android studio and starting a new project but  I get a message says:

> **Refreshing '...' gradle project Gradle: download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle3.3-all.zip**

So I went to the path

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3-all.zip.part

Unfortunately no thing have been downloaded (the size of the gradle-3.3-all.zip.part file is 0 kB).
and my internet speed is not bad.

Comment: download gradle manually from this link https://gradle.org/releases/ and set the path and try

Comment: I did that and I get   Refreshing  '....' gradle project message that forever

Comment: can u post error in picture?

Comment: The message was  Refreshing 'project_name.' gradle project  Now  I get the error message   Error:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3-all.zip.lck (Access is denied)

Comment: Gradle 'JINGER' project refresh failed   \gradle l.zip.lck (Access is denied)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919963/gradle-2-10-taskartifacts-cache-properties-lock-access-is-denied-in-android-st check this link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155505/discussion-between-javafan-and-lingeshwaran).

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\wrapper\
>     dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2r‌​cmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\‌​gradle-3.3-all.zip.l‌​ck
>   (Access is denied)

Probably your GRADLE_HOME variable points to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2".
Ordinary user, of course, cannot write access to "Program Files".

By default it's ${USERPROFILE}/.gradle.

Try remove GRADLE_HOME environment variable (or investigate why it was overridden)

Comment: look am the admin to the pc (Windows 8) and I enter by admin account but even if I want to run the android studio I couldn't do that if not run as administrator  done.

Comment: Have you checked GRADLE_HOME environment variable?

Comment: what do you mean by gradle_home envirnoment variable ?